# bundle下のrubocopが読めない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

`bundle exec rubocop`をやると、どうやら古いバージョンの`rubocop`を使っているようなのですが、どうすればbundlerで管理しているrubocopを使えるのでしょうか？

```
$bundle exec rubocop -v

warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby22, which recognizes
warning: 2.2.x-compliant syntax, but you are running 2.3.1.
warning: please see https://github.com/whitequark/parser#compatibility-with-ruby-mri.
0.35.1

$rubocop -v

0.46.0

$which rubocop

/usr/local/bin/rubocop


$bundle exec which rubocop

/usr/local/bin/rubocop
```

Answer (score 1):

Gemfile.lock に書かれている rubocop のバージョンが古いためだと思います。

`bundle update rubocop` を実行するのがいいと思います。